# Get the changes done by ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

When we use `DataSet` and `DataAdapter` to do certain modification (Insert, Update, Delete) on table then we use `DataSet.GetChanges()` method to get the change information.

But when I am using `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` to do the modifications on table then can I get the modification information? And if yes, then please tell me how to access it.

Comment: No, but since you have created the sql-command and added the parameters you should know what has changed.

Comment: You are right. But if I use stored procedure which do multiple modification then it's hard to know the changes.

Comment: @Amit, Yet there's no way to get that information.

Comment: @Amit: if you use a stored-procedure which does additional work, the `DataTable`/`DataSet` wouldn't notice those changes either. It just knows the current state and what sql-command if a row was modified. So if you'd pass sql-parameters manually to the `SqlCommand` you'd know just as much as a `DataSet`/`DataTable`. If you use `out`-parameter(s) you could also retrieve those value(s) after `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataSet` and `DataAdapter` work in a whole different way than `SqlCommand`.
The only available information of the later is `ExecuteNonQuery` return value:

> Type: System.Int32
>   The number of rows affected.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can I get the row's information and it's data which are modified?

Comment: @Amit, as I wrote, no. לא.